# room not returning results for livedata

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to return LiveData from Android Room. I am having trouble returning the result as LiveData.

Here is the excerpt from Dao

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM transaction_table")
  LiveData<List<MyTransaction>> getAllTransactions();

  @Query("SElECT * FROM transaction_table")
  List<MyTransaction> getMyTransaction();
```

The getAllTransactions() call runs without an exception but, does not return the results. On the other hand, getMyTransactions() returns select query results.

in viewmodel: `myLiveData = repository. getAllTransactions()`

in activity:

```
 mViewModel!!.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer<List< MyTransaction >> { repositories: List< MyTransaction > ->
})
```

whats wrong?

Comment: please provide the code for how this data is handled (viewmodel, UI), this is not sufficent

Comment: updted the question

Comment: @AskQ check the answer and see if it solves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this `myLiveData = repository. getAllTransactions()` part is done When you create instance of viewmodel.

Before you start to observe `myLiveData` the query result has been posted.

What you should do is to make a method in `ViewModel`

```
fun getAllTransactions():LiveData<List<MyTransaction>> {
  return repository. getAllTransactions();
}
```

And in the activity,

```
mViewModel!!.getAllTransactions().observe(this, Observer<List< MyTransaction >> { repositories: List< MyTransaction > ->
//your code goes here
})
```

Comment: do i need to call removeObservers? like val localdata = githubListViewModel?.loadLocalData()
                localdata?.removeObservers(this) before observing?

Comment: underlying data structure manages that, it does not keep duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with `myLiveData = repository.getAllTransactions()`.

Since `getAllTransactions()` returns a `LiveData`, assigning `repository.getAllTransactions` to a member variable is similar to registering an observer on it and the observer, in your case `myLiveData`, won't be triggered or notified unless there's a change in the underlying database.

Try the following,

```
// in viewmodel
fun myLiveData() = repository.getAllTransactions()

//try to log in the activity and you will see the data
Log.i("activity",mViewModel.myLiveData().value.toString())

//since myLiveData function returns a livedata, you can register observers on to it as well
mViewModel!!.myLiveData().observe(this, Observer<List< MyTransaction >> { repositories: List< MyTransaction > ->
})
```